# How can make Drawtext Slide Animation on ffmpeg - Left top corner to Right bottom corner of video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

I have found the command for overlaying the text "HelloWorld" right bottom to left top. but its not accurately working on edge to edge , instead its starting above the bottom edge and ends below the top edge. Below is the command i used.

```
ffmpeg -i "tmp/output_2.mp4" -vf "drawtext='fontfile=DejaVu Sans:text=HelloWorld:fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:y=h-50*t:x=w-(t-4.5)*(w+tw)/15'" -vcodec libx264 -crf 15 "tmp/watermark_output_2.mp4
```

I need to make a command variations that works on 4 different type of drawtext hover on video.

1. Right bottom to Left top
2. Left top to Right bottom
3. Right top to left bottom
4. Left bottom to right top

I am not familiar with the variables used in the x,y directions of drawtext.

Please help me out with this, thank you.

Comment: use lerp function: `:x='lerp(0,w-tw,t/5)':y='lerp(0,h-th,t/5)'` where 5 is duration of video

Comment: getting error

```
No such filter: 'w-tw'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[libmp3lame @ 0x55b5d41aa840] 4 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!

```

used command

```
ffmpeg -i "split_0001.flv" -vf "drawtext='fontfile=DejaVu Sans:text=HelloWorld:fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:y=h-50*t:x='lerp(0,w-tw,t/5)':y='lerp(0,h-th,t/5)'" -vcodec libx264 -crf 15 "split_0001_merged1.flv"

```

Comment: `ffmpeg -t 5 -i "input.mp4" -vf "
drawtext=font='DejaVu Sans'
:text=Hell
:fontcolor=white
:fontsize=30
:x='lerp(0,w-tw,t/5)'
:y='lerp(0,h-th,t/5)'
" -crf 15 out.mp4` check quotation marks

Comment: It works! Can you explain the lerp and x, y functions so I can build my own Thank you.

Comment: lerp(x, y, z) → Return linear interpolation between x and y by amount of z. for example: lerp(0,1900,t/5) → from 0 to 1900. time from 0 to 5. third value must be from 0 to 1. so current frame time divided by 5 seconds of duration.

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов why not turn it into an answer when explaining the commands anyways?